# Installation for Today extension

Tags: widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am playing with IOS 8 new features : Today extension. But many times I have to install the main app two times to get new Widgets from my app to display in IOS Today. Does it happen for everyone ? or it just my mistake in configuration.
Thanks,

Comment: I think it was happening to me too. I didn't pay much attention to since it's still beta.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say that it's a bug. It has been happening to me all the time with Xcode6b7 and iOS8b5. I found out that I could make the extension appear by pressing 'edit' and removing another extension (such as tomorrow or calendar).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issues when I'm trying to update my widget.

Even when I installed my app via the TestFlight app, I had to install it twice to see the updated widget.

*It's surely a bug which isn't even fixed in the current Xcode Beta, which I'm using since the release.*

But you shouldn't worry whether your updated widget will be installed when the users are updating it via the App Store. When I tried updating my widgets via the App Store, I didn't get any problems.